# Amazon S3 and cyrillic letters in file name

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have a problem uploading file to cloud that contains cyrillic letters (right_file_кириллица.csv). My code is:

```
ObjectMetadata meta = new ObjectMetadata();
meta.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(s3Bucket, f.asPath(), new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toString("UTF-8").getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))), meta);
PutObjectResult result = s3Client.putObject(por);
```

bos - this is ByteArrayOutputStream. And this cause exception:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: A796905192C41ED5)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:937)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:506)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:273)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3660)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1432)
```

I set encoding UTF-8 in all places where it possible. So, does anybody know how to fix that?
Thanks

Comment: What is your aws-sdk version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information needs to be set in the ContentType and not in the Content-Encoding:

```
ObjectMetadata meta = new ObjectMetadata();
meta.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Content-Encoding is typically used to indicate if the body has been compressed (like setting values gzip or deflate)