# unable to store files to S3 which has chinese character (Java)

Tags: java, amazon-s3

i need to save a file(String) to S3, which contains some chinese characters, and it always failed due to those character, here is my code:

```
# generate output stream with the file 
byte[] bytes = file.getBytes("UTF-8");
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bytes.length);
out.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

ObjectMetadata md = new ObjectMetadata();
md.setContentLength(bytes.length);
md.setContentType("text/csv;charset=UTF-8");
md.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");

# save to S3
client.putObject("myBucket", "keyName", stream, md);
```

and the error i got:

```
    com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to unmarshall error response (Character reference "&#)
..

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Character reference "&#
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.amazonaws.util.XpathUtils.documentFrom(XpathUtils.java:67) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.3.19.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3ErrorResponseHandler.handle(S3ErrorResponseHandler.java:63) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.3.19.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3ErrorResponseHandler.handle(S3ErrorResponseHandler.java:38) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.3.19.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:558) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.3.19.jar:na]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon S3 and cyrillic letters in file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677161/amazon-s3-and-cyrillic-letters-in-file-name)

Comment: The character set is part of the content type, not content encoding. `md.setContentType("text/csv;charset=UTF-8");`

Comment: @dnault: updated my post, i still got the same error.

Comment: Try removing the call to setContentEncoding.

Comment: @dnault: removed the call to setContentEncoding too, still not working..

Comment: I would set a breakpoint in AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse and see what the amazon server is returning. Perhaps it's returning some XML that the client can't parse... and knowing what that XML looks like might help diagnose the issue.